# Webdav feature questions lock documents and revision control

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

1. Can we have lock/unlock of documents or revision control with WebDAV server?
2. Can user change the file name?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine supports both locking and versioning.

   - Please see here how to implement locking: 
     https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/creating_class_2_webdav_server/
   - Please see here how implement versioning: https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/creating_deltav/
     Please note that this will NOT enable versions list in MS Office UI. MS Office is using its own proprietary patented protocols to list versions.
2. Yes, you can rename files and folders. Renaming is a move operation. You can program it in IHierarchyItemAsync.[MoveToAsync](https://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IHierarchyItemAsync.MoveToAsync.htm)() method implementation.